# Why java dynamic server just works on stand alone Tomcat but not eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

First of all, i don't know if i wrote the question correctly or not.

I have a dynamic web server that I developed on eclipse, and when I run it on eclipse, using Tomcat 8.0.33 i get this

[image]

however, if i compiled and build the project and extracted the war file, then put that war file into the work `web apps` folder into Tomcat installation directory, and then run Tomcat from terminal using `startup.sh`, it works perfectly, see please

[image]

i tried another version of Tomcat, 8.0.24, and the same problem happened.

i am using eclipse `Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)` on `mac os El Captine`

#### Update 1

Maybe because I deleted the `web content` folder and i am putting my files in `src/main/webapp`

and that is what I do in pom

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Do you think so? if yes how to solve it please ?

Comment: try with cleaning the project

Comment: @SpringLearner i already did hundreds of times per say

Comment: I recently got this ERROR and was trying to clean it and everything I did was in vain, finally I realized It was cause of my **index.html** was inside WEB-INF, It **must be on Web Content**, I'm a noobie on this matter cause I'm studying it right now, but It solves this same problem. Make a look about your Tomcat location, doing double click on tomcat server on eclipse

Comment: @M.Mariscal I don't have Web Content folder, i am using maven to specify another folder, which is `java/man/webapp`,

Comment: You are just telling, that something doesnt work. Better tell what you tried to achieve and how you tried that.

Comment: @Stefan I tried to ask her, I tried to clean the project, I tried to use apache 8.0.24, I tried to see the log (nothing was there)

Comment: The problem is a 404 status, so the reason is, there is no file or servlet listening at that url.

Comment: @Stefan please read my update

Comment: @SpringLearner please read my update

Comment: @M.Mariscal please read my update

Comment: @Stefan if OP is not changing anything apart from compiling and generating war then why will it work in tomcat server but not in eclipse tomcat. IF some servlet is not listening then it will show 404 in both the cases

Comment: The context path is different!

Comment: @Stefan what is context path please? did you mean content path?

Comment: .../SemanticRecommenderWebservices/...

Comment: @Stefan it is the same in both screenshots, I'm pretty sure of that mate

Comment: Yes, and that might be the problem, mate.

Comment: @Stefan the URL is the same, one works on tomcat, and the same one doesn't work on eclipse, I couldn't find out how this info is helpful to solve the problem. I really think that eclipse is not able to find the correct folder instead of web content, but i'm not sure what to do since i already told maven what is the folder, and it sounds like i did it correctly since tomcat could get me

Answer (score 0):

If the project is webtools dynamic project, you can edit the file **$PROJECT_HOME/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component**. Modify the  attribute value of `source-path` of `wb-resource` element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
    <wb-module deploy-name="SemanticRecommenderWebservices">
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/src/main/webapp"/>
        <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/java"/>
        <property name="context-root" value="SemanticRecommenderWebservices"/>
        <property name="java-output-path" value="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes"/>
    </wb-module>
</project-modules>
```